# Use an If or Case statement to create an amended field for a new view in existing db in SSMS2008

Tags: sql, if-statement, view, case, ssms

New Field = If Field X = 0 and Field Y = 12 THEN 15 ELSE New Field = Field X

The following worked fine in ACCESS,

Amended Run No: IIf([001_DETAILS]![tlRunNo]=0 And [001_DETAILS]![tlDocType]=41,"TSH",[001_DETAILS]![tlRunNo])

(ACCESS didn't seem bothered that I was inserting text into field that otherwise had integers - I didn't care either as it's what I wanted).

I have tried typing and pasting variations on this into the "column" area of SSMS's "Criteria" part but none work (changing !'s and _'s for "." etc).

Am I perhaps trying to do something that I shouldn't. Incidentally I'm fairly sure this could be done easily enough in POWERPIVOT once in EXCEL but I want to do as much as possible before the data gets to EXCEL. It may also be the case that there is some other approach that I can take but I'm still perplexed as to why this apparently straightforward transformation is seemingly so difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can just do this with a calculated column in the view definition:

```
NewField = CASE WHEN FieldX = 0 AND FieldY = 12 THEN 15 ELSE FieldX END
```

Comment: I am using SSMS 2008 which is querying an MS SQL 2012 db. I am in the Query Designer window creating a view.

Comment: Jnk thanks for the suggestion but this appeared to make no difference, the response was "unable to parse". It is a long select query using 9 tables and it works. However I wish to add a field (actually two fields) to it using the logic I have mentioned and that Jnk adapted. This was and is easy in Excel or Access why is it so tricky in MS SQL?

Comment: Sorry that's two questions then. 1 - what's the solution to my problem. 2 Why is it a problem in this and not in Excel/Access? thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually one more detail to clarify, though I think it makes no difference. What I actually want is, NewField = CASE WHEN FieldX = 0 AND FieldY = 12 THEN 15 ELSE FieldZ END. All the fields are from the same table.

Comment: CASE WHEN ABC001.DETAILS.tlRunNo = 0 AND ABC001.DETAILS.tlDocType = 41 THEN 70060 ELSE ABC001.DETAILS.tlGLCode AS [GL Anal Code]
I tried typing that into the select section of the sql (as opposed to using the Access type graphical criteria pane).Result here, "incorrect syntax near 'AS'". Still perplexed.

Comment: OK, it worked. Thanks. Turns out a little typo, actually an omission, was causing my angst. I wasn't saying END, never had to say that before. A relief because this was otherwise a very surprising shortcoming. Also works equally well entered into criteria area or typed/pasted into sql area - as you would expect.